# Magento - products disappear from cart in seconds

Tags: .htaccess, magento, e-commerce

I'm having problems with keeping new items in the cart on a Magento store. It worked fine until a couple of days ago and i can't really recall what could cause it to start acting like this, as no major changes were implemented.

It acts like the session length for each user would only be a second or so. After you add a product in the cart (works normal), pretty much anything you try to do from there, it returns that the cart is empty. (like your session would expire already)

File permissions on the folders that handle the sessions is 755 and the session length set in Magento back end is 86400 (24 hours)

Same session length is also added in htaccess file (php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400)

What would be some ways to even start troubleshooting this, i'm pretty dumbstruck right now and clueless on how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: Check the cookie value; see if the session id changes. Check the content of the session file corresponding to the sessionid, and see if the content changes, get cleared, or if the file is removed altogether.

Comment: Do logged in customers also log out quickly? If not then it's not a session problem after all.

Comment: Did you change the cookie domain?

Comment: We have similar issue with disappearing products in cart. In our case it was related with wrong server time configuration which made session to be valid only for 4 seconds. After right configuration everything got back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code on your server to **find out what time PHP thinks it is**:

```
<?php
//Print the current date, time, and time zone. echo(gmstrftime("It is %a on %b %d, %Y, %X time zone: %Z",time()));
?>
```

If the time on the server is off, correct it (and preferably set a cron script to repeat that once a day).